# How are Whole Slide Images handled in Deep Learning

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I was planning on doing some classification/segmentation on whole slide images. Since the images are huge, I was wondering about the methods that can be applied to process them. So far I've come across techniques that split the image into multiple parts, process those parts and combine the results. However, I would like to know more about other better approaches and if it's the good one. Any reference to existing literature would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) has a feature for generating patches from slide images efficiently.

This benchmark shows how it works. It can generate about 25,000 64x64 patches a second in the 8 basic orientations from an SVS file:

https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/100#issuecomment-493960943

It's handy for training. I don't know how that compares to the other patch generation systems people use.

Answer (score 1):

To read these images, the standard library is "open-slide" [https://openslide.org/api/python/]. By "open-slide" you can read, e.g., patches or thumbnails.

For basic image processing operations like filtering, "libvips" and its python binding "pyvips" is quick and convenient to use [https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/vimage.html].

If you need to pass data (like random patches) to a machine learning model, I would personally suggest "PyDmed". When training, e.g., a classifier or a generative model, the loading speed of "PyDmed" is suitable for feeding batches of data to GPU(s).

Here is the link to PyDmed public repo:
https://github.com/amirakbarnejad/PyDmed

Here is the link to PyDmed quick start:
https://amirakbarnejad.github.io/Tutorial/tutorial_section1.html

Answer (score 0):

As akbarnejad mentioned, my preference is to use [openslide](https://openslide.org/api/python/).

I usually end up writing bespoke dataloaders to feed into pytorch models that use openslide to first do some simple segmentation using various thresholds of a low resolution (thumbnail) image of the slide to get patch coordinates and then pull out the relevant patches of tissue for feeding into the training model.

There are a few good examples of this and tools that try to make it simpler for both pytorch and Keras -

**Pytorch**
[wsi-preprocessing](https://github.com/lucasrla/wsi-preprocessing)

**Keras**
[Deeplearning-digital-pathology](https://github.com/zhaoxuanma/Deeplearning-digital-pathology)

**Both**
[deep-openslide](https://github.com/shaziaakbar/deep-openslide)